# How to cache the response of API calls in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am working in Flutter App to get the items from API. I want to cache the API response for 12 hours. Every 12 hours the response will be changed. Once the 12 hours completed then I need to fetch it from Internet. I used the below code to get it from internet.

```
Future<List<Playlist>> fetchPlaylistByChannelId({String channelId}) async {
Map<String, String> parameters = {
  'part': 'snippet,contentDetails',
  'channelId': channelId,
  'maxResults': '10',
  'key': API_KEY,
};
Uri uri = Uri.https(
  _baseUrl,
  '/youtube/v3/playlists',
  parameters,
);
Map<String, String> headers = {
  HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
};

// Get Playlist details
var response = await http.get(uri, headers: headers);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  var data = json.decode(response.body);
  List<dynamic> playListJson = data['items'];

  // Fetch all play list
  List<Playlist> playLists = [];
  playListJson.forEach(
    (json) => playLists.add(
      Playlist.fromMap(
        json["id"],
        json["snippet"],
        json["contentDetails"],
      ),
    ),
  );
  return playLists;
} else {
  throw json.decode(response.body)['error']['message'];
}   }
```

Please help me out this.

Answer (score 19):

Include [flutter_cache_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager) in `pubspec.yaml`.

Now define a cache manager

```
import 'package:flutter_cache_manager/flutter_cache_manager.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;

// Custom Implementation of CacheManager
// by extending the BaseCacheManager abstract class
class MyCacheManager extends BaseCacheManager {
  static const key = "customCache";

  static MyCacheManager _instance;

  // singleton implementation 
  // for the custom cache manager
  factory MyCacheManager() {
    if (_instance == null) {
      _instance = new MyCacheManager._();
    }
    return _instance;
  }

  // pass the default setting values to the base class
  // link the custom handler to handle HTTP calls 
  // via the custom cache manager
  MyCacheManager._()
      : super(key,
            maxAgeCacheObject: Duration(hours: 12),
            maxNrOfCacheObjects: 200,
            fileFetcher: _myHttpGetter);

  @override
  Future<String> getFilePath() async {
    var directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    return path.join(directory.path, key);
  }

  static Future<FileFetcherResponse> _myHttpGetter(String url,
      {Map<String, String> headers}) async {
    HttpFileFetcherResponse response;
    // Do things with headers, the url or whatever.
    try {
      var res = await http.get(url, headers: headers);
      // add a custom response header
      // to regulate the caching time
      // when the server doesn't provide cache-control
      res.headers.addAll({'cache-control': 'private, max-age=120'});
      response = HttpFileFetcherResponse(res);
    } on SocketException {
      print('No internet connection');
    }
    return response;
  }
}
```

Now use

```
class HttpProvider {
  Future<Response> getData(String url, Map<String, String> headers) async {
    var file = await MyCacheManager().getSingleFile(url, headers: headers);
    if (file != null && await file.exists()) {
      var res = await file.readAsString();
      return Response(res, 200);
    }
    return Response(null, 404);
  }
}
```

Details at https://referbruv.com/blog/posts/caching-get-request-calls-using-flutter-cache-manager and https://proandroiddev.com/flutter-lazy-loading-data-from-network-with-caching-b7486de57f11

---

**UPDATE: flutter_cache_manager 2.0.0**

> There is no longer a need to extend on BaseCacheManager, you can directly call the constructor. The BaseCacheManager is now only an interface. CacheManager is the implementation you can use directly.

check [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager)

Comment: Thanks for sharing it. I will apply it and update the status.

Comment: @PhilipJebaraj flutter_cache_manager uses SQLite. If you are already using SQLite in your Flutter app, be careful. I remember reading that a Flutter app can have troubles if it opens two SQLite databases. So you should configure flutter_cache_manager to use the same SQLite database that your app otherwise uses.

Comment: @PhilipJebaraj Don't forget to give the accepted answer!

Comment: I have used the above code, I am able to get the result. How do I know whether the data is coming from cache or internet. I am calling the method like this. `final result = await ApiService.instance.getData();
    print(result.body);`

Comment: I tested the service by changing the id parameter, but the result is not changed. It is showing old result so the items are coming from cache only. Now I want to get the items for different playlist id at the same time. How can I do that? Do I need to include multiple cache manager?. Please suggest me.

Comment: Where one can find the the id. Is it a url parameter ?

Comment: Yes Dev. It's an URL parameter.

Comment: Cache should had been using url as the key for cache but let me see if i m missing something.

Comment: Thanks for the letting me know. If the URL changed then am seeing the different result. I want to know for the id parameter.

Comment: Try flutter_cache_store (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_store). This package it is more configurable than the basic one from which this is forked. . Can be easily switched to each other. Basics will be same just try getFile and may be then CacheStorePolicy. Actual problem may be that the filename returned from the service is same for all ids.

Comment: Can you try adding in _myHttpGetter     res.headers.addAll({"Content-Disposition","inline; filename="+urlid});

Answer (score 3):

Another way of caching is by using hive a No-SQL database it is faster to retrieve documents and is easy to use. And when users come online just refresh the data in hive

[image]

For more details check:https://github.com/shashiben/Anime-details to know how to cache using hive

Comment: or store in shared preferences?

Comment: Storing lots of data in shared prefs can cause performance issues.